# Is there an existing format / protocol for streaming video with per-frame metadata?

Tags: video, video-streaming, metadata, protocols, video-encoding

I wish to stream a video with dynamic metadata. I know I could just steam the video and metadata separately, but ideally I'd like them to be bound permanently.

Is there an existing protocol / encoding / format that does this? Is there a better way to approach this?

I could store the data in each frame using steganography, but this is not an ideal solution and is rather hacky.

[Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/index.html) looks as though it might have some tools that would go some way towards simultaneously streaming metadata, but I'm worried this would be a bit of an overkill, and as previously mentioned, this is not an ideal solution.